# Supabase Auth with the Next.js App Router tutorial throwing server error on createMiddlewareClient({req,res})

Tags: next.js13, next-auth, supabase

When following the Supabase Auth with the Next.js App Router tutorial, the initial development of the server throws an error

[image: Server Error shown on initial run of server]

My .env.local file is initialized with the correct url and key.

Here is my middleware.ts file

```
import { createMiddlewareClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()

  // Create a Supabase client configured to use cookies
  const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res })

  // Refresh session if expired - required for Server Components
  // https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#managing-session-with-middleware
  await supabase.auth.getSession()

  return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways I've found to fix this problem. The first can be implemented on a file-to-file basis. The second fixes the problem across the project.

1. wherever you get the error, pass in your supabaseKey and supabaseUrl as another object in the parameters.
   looking at the d.ts file the context is passed in as an object {req, res} and the supabaseKey, supabaseUrl are passed in as a seperate object

example:

```
const supabaseKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY

const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL

const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res }, { supabaseKey, supabaseUrl })
```

d.ts file:

```
declare function createMiddlewareClient<Database = any, SchemaName extends string & keyof Database = 'public' extends keyof Database ? 'public' : string & keyof Database, Schema extends GenericSchema = Database[SchemaName] extends GenericSchema ? Database[SchemaName] : any>(context: {
    req: NextRequest;
    res: NextResponse;
}, { supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, options, cookieOptions }?: {
    supabaseUrl?: string;
    supabaseKey?: string;
    options?: SupabaseClientOptionsWithoutAuth<SchemaName>;
    cookieOptions?: CookieOptionsWithName;
}): SupabaseClient<Database, SchemaName, Schema>;
```

2. go to your .env.local file and make sure your supabase key is named:
   NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
   For some reason, they project is initialized as NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY

Comment: You should only need to do option 2 here. I can't see any tutorials on the Supabase website that has reference to `NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY` as an environment variable, would you mind pointing me to where you saw this?